# Add Files and Select Multiple Targets in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have over 100 projects in my XCode and when I add a new file or class I have to select each target one by one to add it to it. Is there a way to select multiple targets instead?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to have targets that don't duplicate each others files. E.g. some targets are libraries that are used by some others, and eventually there's an app or a unit test target that uses them. In this case there's no need to have the same file in multiple targets.

So consider refactoring the common files to a common library target that you can reference from the other targets. In this case when you add a file, you can add it to just that library, and it will be automatically resolved (*linked*) in the other targets.

Note also that in this case the file you add is only compiled once, and the compilation result is reused in various dependant targets, as opposed to compiling a separate version of that file for each target.

If that's not an option for you, an alternative is to generate the Xcode project file using some tool like CMake, [GN](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn), or a custom script that can write xcodeproj files (there are libraries to do that in various languages).